# How to test Meteor.users with Mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor

I have a function as follows:

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.methods({
    addUser: function (newUser) {
        check(newUser, { email: String, password: String });
        userId = Accounts.createUser(newUser);
        return userId;
    },
    getUser: function (userID) {
        check(userID, String);
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: userID}).fetch();
    }
});
```

And I am trying to test this function using Mocha:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
let testUser;
describe('Users', () => {
    it("Add User", (done) => {

        testUser = {email: 'test@test.test', password: 'test'};

        try {
            testUser._id = Meteor.call('addUser', testUser);
            console.log(Accounts.users.find({_id: testUser._id}).fetch());
            done();
        } catch (err) {
            assert.fail();
        }
    });

    it("Get user", (done) => {
        try {
            Meteor.call('getUser', testUser._id);
            done();
        } catch (err) {
            assert.fail();
        }
    });
});
```

And I know that the meteor call with 'addUser' works, because the console.log after that returns the user that I just made and the first test passes when I run it with "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha"

But then I come to the second testing part, where I try to get the user with the meteor call 'getUser', but then I get stuck:

'Cannot call method 'find' of undefined'

Now I know that the difference is that I use 'Meteor.users' instead of 'Account.users' to find the user, but I am totally in the dark what the difference is between these two. Should I replace all the Meteor.users method calls with Accounts.user method calls or not? How would you test this?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this post, since I have dealt with the same issue some hours ago.

As I can see in your code, your testUser is defined in your first unit ( `it("Add User"...){}`). I advise you not to use the value from the first unit in the second unit.

You may rather use beforeEach and afterEach to have a clean setup for each unit and then create a new user in the second test unit. You should also clean up your db after each unit:

```
describe('Users', () => {

    // use this for each test
    let testUser;


    beforeEach(() => {
        // let's always create a new clean testUser object
        testUser = {email: 'test@test.test', password: 'test'};
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // Remove the user to keep our db clean
        if (testUser._id)
            Meteor.users.remove(testUser._id);
    });

    it("Add User", (done) => {
        testUser._id = Meteor.call('addUser', testUser);
        const users = Meteor.users.find({_id: testUser._id}).fetch();
        const user = users[0];
        assert.isNotNull(user);
        assert.isDefined(user);
        assert.equal(user._id, testUser._id);
        done();

    });

    it("Get user", (done) => {
        // get a new id from our previously tested
        // (and assume to be working) function
        testUser._id = Meteor.call('addUser', testUser);

        const user = Meteor.call('getUser', testUser._id);
        assert.isNotNull(user);
        assert.isDefined(user);
        assert.equal(user._id, testUser._id);
        done();
    });
});
```

I also found, that your 'getUser' method returns an array, so I changed it to:

```
getUser: function (userID) {
    check(userID, String);
    const users = Meteor.users.find({_id: userID}).fetch();
    return users[0];
}
```

All tested and running.

Comment: You actually don't need to use a Meteor method to create a user account for tests. Having a meteor method that creates a user account specifically for a test is quite dirty. You can use the ```dburles:factory``` package to create a test user (with or without roles) and then can execute validated methods by doing: ```methodName._execute( userId , data );``` where the userId is an object: ```{ userId: userId }``` and ```data``` are the args for the method. You can also call normal meteor methods passing a userId as a context too but there isn't space in this comment to demo

Comment: Mocking the behavior you don't want to test is the correct way, I agree. In this question the method that creates a user account is the one to be tested and not a method specifically designed for a test. Therefore I tried to show a useful answer, how @justanoob solves the issue with minimum effort. I assumed, that for other tests, where user creation is implied a mocking collection is set up.

Comment: I don't think this answers the poster's original question, though. It doesn't explain the 'find is undefined' error, as far as I can tell, though I may have missed some detail. I'm having the same problem as the OP, except that BOTH Accounts.users.find AND Meteor.users.find throw the same error: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined. In my case, I am not creating in one unit and checking in the other. I'm absolutely baffled by this and can find no answers anywhere.

Comment: @Dave similar did occur to me when testing users as part of a package test with mocha. In my case the whole users collection was undefined and I just created it at the very beginning of my tests as new Mongo.Collection which solved this issue for me. Maybe I elobrate that again and edit my answer soon.